# Extract css from html

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a clean way to grab and remove all the css between the `<style></style>` tags.
For example:

```
<style>
foo
</style>

content

<style>
bar
</style>

here
```

By the end of the process I should have a string with `content\nhere` (everything not between the style tags) and an array of matches between the style tags `['foo', 'bar']` or something similar. I've tried a lot of different regex approaches and none of the seemed to work for me. (I'm no regex pro though..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not access html with regular expressions. Just try DomDocument instead. It 's more cleaner and easier to access.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('Your HTML here');

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style');
for ($i = $elements->length; --$i >= 0;) {
    $elements->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($elements->item($i));
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

This code is an example and not tested.

Comment: Using the DOM is the good way for this kind of task, but don't imagine that using regex is 'too expensive', because using the DOM is slower *(in particular, you must pay the cost of the DOM tree building)*. But as I said before it stays the most clean way.

Comment: @Marcel Nice approach here. Is it really faster then regex?

Comment: Don't forget to store or display `$dom->saveHTML()`

Comment: You could use foreach on the $elements.

Comment: @MK: no it's not possible, because `$elements` is not an array but a nodeList, and elements must be removed from the end to the begining.

Comment: foreach results in problems, when you try to delete elements from the dom tree.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this issue on php.net a minute ago.

Comment: @MK Note that you can extract the css with `$elements->item($i)->textContent`

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution much more since it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: $css = $dom->saveHTML($elements->item($i));

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
$html = "<style>css css css</style>my html<style>more css</style>";
preg_match_all("/<style>(.*?)<\/style>/is", $html, $matches);

$html = str_replace($matches[0], '', $html);
$css = implode("\n", $matches[1]);

echo $html; // my html
echi $css; // css css css \n more css
```

Originally I was looking for a pure regex solution, but this is fine for me.